# dplyr commands in UDF

Tags: r, dplyr

I need to wrap the below dplyr command in a R user defined function.

It should have 4 parameters -

- filter -- any filtering condition within filter( )
- scales ---  any function from scales (not just percent) package
- variable to select for mutation
- df

Code -

```
val <- Cash_Collateral %>% dplyr::filter(Collateral == 'Non-Residential') %>% 
      mutate(LRF_Net_ActualVsForecast = scales::percent(LRF_Net_ActualVsForecast, accuracy = 0.1)) %>% 
      select(LRF_Net_ActualVsForecast) %>% pull()
```

Comment: Is this homework? What did you try? Where did it fail?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in base R:

```
f <- function(df, filter, var, FUN, ...)
{
  filter <- as.list(match.call())$filter
  ss <- eval(filter, envir = df, enclos = parent.frame())
  FUN(subset(df, ss)[[deparse(substitute(var))]], ...)
}
```

For example:

```
df <- data.frame(a = 1:5, b = letters[1:5])
df
#>   a b
#> 1 1 a
#> 2 2 b
#> 3 3 c
#> 4 4 d
#> 5 5 e

df %>% f(filter = a > 1 & a < 5, var = b, FUN = paste, collapse = " ")
#> [1] "b c d"
```